# Why does compileJava is actually skipped?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

So, I created a java project with gradle and tried to observe all tasks which may be executed when I run `gradle -m build`. Here they are:

```
:compileJava SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:jar SKIPPED
:assemble SKIPPED
:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:processTestResources SKIPPED
:testClasses SKIPPED
:test SKIPPED
:check SKIPPED
:build SKIPPED
```

Why does compileJava was skipped? I tried to compile fresh sources, which is obviously not up-to-date. Now, when I run just `gradle build` what I recieve is :

```
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
```

So, the compileJava task is actually executed, but it's not clear why it's makked as skipped in `gradle -m build` execution?

Comment: imho actually a good question, as the output would indicate: nothing to do for `compileJava`.  if you compare this to the behaviour of `make -n`, where the actions properly show up, this only shows you the task, that would run, but not considering the current state of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you asked to skip every task by using the `-m` option.

Quote from [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html):

> ```
> -m, --dry-run
>
> Runs the build with all task actions disabled. See Section 11.7, “Dry Run”.
> ```